# Forge Data and View API broken, no longer uploads large files

Tags: c#, rest, authentication, autodesk, autodesk-forge

I have been using the View and Data API for a while now to view autodesk content. Quite recently after the authenticaton versions changed I seemed to not be able to upload my queen elizabeth hospital model.

Do I need to migrate to v2 for it to continue functioning as before as all I can manage now is a 7.5 mega byte file after continual attempts at upload?

Comment: You definitely need to think about migrating to v2, but this should not block you right now. Have you tried using a new and fresh bucket?

Comment: Hi, yessir I try a new bucket per project and the results seem the same.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: I think someone had the same issue recently, and they started to receive Error 401 (meaning 'Unauthorized'), and they solved it by setting the bucket AuthId specifically.

Comment: Common reasons for this are (1) failing to correctly scope your accesstoken (see https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/overview/scopes/) or (2) Your file to upload is too large and you need to use a resumable upload instead (see https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-resumable-PUT/). But if this (or the above suggestions) don't help, we need to see some sample code and a file to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Keep style professional, this is not facebook

Answer (score 0):

You asked for the code, So here it is, I upgraded this code to version **v2** and I am not getting a token anymore. I figure this is preventing me from moving on from the deprecated version I am using.
 #note below the version is v1 and this works!

```
    public static string Authenticate()
    {
        // (1) Build request 
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = new System.Uri(baseApiUrl);

        // Set resource/end point
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Resource = "authentication/v1/authenticate";
        request.Method = Method.POST;

        // Set required parameters 
        request.AddParameter("client_id", consumerKey);
        request.AddParameter("client_secret", consumerSecret);
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        request.AddParameter("scope", "data:read data:create data:write bucket:read bucket:create");


        // (2) Execute request and get response
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        // Save response. This is to see the response for our learning.
        m_lastResponse = response;

        // Get the access token. 
        string accessToken = "";
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            JsonDeserializer deserial = new JsonDeserializer();
            Share_Model_OSSClasses loginResponse = deserial.Deserialize<Share_Model_OSSClasses>(response);
            accessToken = loginResponse.access_token;
        }

        return accessToken;
    }



public class Share_Model_OSSClasses
{
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public string expires_in { get; set; } // expiry time in seconds. (30 min) 
    public string access_token { get; set; }
}
```